# Package name changing improperly

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I changed my package name using the method of refractor > rename after deselecting 'compact empty middle package' in project window as shown in this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-rITYZQj0A

Now my project window shows the changed name, each of my java files show changed name, even my manifest also shows the updated name...but when I log `getPackageName()` it still returns the old name. Am I missing something here ?

Update 1:
When trying to access my raw resources using uri, even then they are being accessed only by old package name...

Comment: Which parts of manifest were changed to the new package?

Comment: There is a big annotation on the video saying "This is the wrong way"

Comment: the package property in `manifest` tag and also all my actvity, services, etc which I declared using .<classname> are displayed as <new package>.<classname>...

Comment: @Curlycorvus yeah I forgot to mention that I clicked the correct link in the video...updated my ques...

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution : It appears that changing package name in the described way does not take effect as the appId defined in build.gradle file has precedence over manifest file. There is an issue registered at :
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=109072

as of now the guys at google doesn't consider it a serious issue...can't blame them...